# sql query show status code without using statuscode table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I show the status codes in my output based on the table structure below?

**Table name:**

Request

**Columns:**

```
RequestID,RequestMessage,RequestStatusID,RequestPriorityID
```

**Example**,

Assuming the RequestStatusID translates to:

```
1 = IN_PROGRESS, 2 = CANCELED, 3 = COMPLETED
```

Just for the record I’m not allowed to create a new table to hold the request status. 
I have to somehow include them in a select statement and it does not matter if the request status codes are hardcoded in the select statement.

I am just curious to find out if there is another way of achieving this without using an extra table.

Comment: you could try using case when

Answer (score 4):

Case statements:

```
SELECT RequestID,
       CASE RequestStatusID 
       WHEN 1 THEN 'IN_PROGRESS'
       WHEN 2 THEN 'CANCELED'
       WHEN 3 THEN 'COMPLETED'
       END,
       RequestDesc,
       RequestPriorityID
 FROM #Request
```

Or the CHOOSE() function if you using SQL server 2012:

```
SELECT RequestID,
       CHOOSE(RequestStatusID,'IN_PROGRESS','CANCELED','COMPLETED'),
       RequestDesc,
       RequestPriorityID
 FROM #Request
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN RequestStatusID = 1 THEN 'IN_PROGRESS'
             WHEN RequestStatusID = 2 THEN 'CANCELED'
             ELSE 'COMPLETED' 
        END StatusName
FROM    tableName
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `case`, but actually I like derived table idea, because it's easier to change in the future:

```
select
    R.*, C.Name as RequestStatusName
from Request as R
    left outer join (values
         (1, 'IN_PROGRESS'),
         (2, 'CANCELED'),
         (3, 'COMPLETED')
    ) as C(Id, Name) on C.Id = R.RequestStatusID
```

So you can add any number of columns you want, for example:

```
select
    R.*,
    C.Name as RequestStatusName,
    C.Description as RequestStatusDescription
from Request as R
    left outer join (values
         (1, 'IN_PROGRESS', 'In progress description'),
         (2, 'CANCELED', 'Canceled description'),
         (3, 'COMPLETED', 'Completed description')
    ) as C(Id, Name, Description) on C.Id = R.RequestStatusID
```

you can create view if you have to join it often:

```
create view vw_RequestStatusNames
as
    select C.Id, C.Name, C.Description
    from (values
         (1, 'IN_PROGRESS', 'In progress description'),
         (2, 'CANCELED', 'Canceled description'),
         (3, 'COMPLETED', 'Completed description')
    ) as C(Id, Name, Description)
```

and use it in joins:

```
select
    R.*,
    C.Name as RequestStatusName,
    C.Description as RequestStatusDescription
from Request as R
    left outer join vw_RequestStatusNames as C on C.Id = R.RequestStatusID
```

**[=> SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8ed7/1)**

Comment: ¿How does this have 0 upvotes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to create a function, you could do with a `Table Valued Function` because you can use it not only here but in other queries as well. Basically easy to maintain and consistent results.

Table Valued Function:

```
create function dbo.RequestStatus()
returns @ReqStatus table
(
  id int identity(1,1), 
  status varchar(50)
)
as
begin

   insert into @ReqStatus values
   ('IN_PROGRESS'), ('CANCELED'), ('COMPLETED')

   return
end

GO
```

Function usage and Query (**[Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/269e6/1)**):

```
select r.RequestID,r.RequestMessage,r.RequestStatusID,
       r.RequestPriorityID, s.status
from Request r join (select id,status from dbo.RequestStatus()) s
    on r.RequestStatusID = s.id
```

Results:

```
| REQUESTID | REQUESTMESSAGE | REQUESTSTATUSID | REQUESTPRIORITYID |      STATUS |
|-----------|----------------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------|
|         1 |           Abcd |               1 |                 1 | IN_PROGRESS |
|         2 |           lmno |               2 |                 1 |    CANCELED |
|         3 |           pqrs |               3 |                 1 |   COMPLETED |
```